# Open embedded audio and video in Word documents

Tags: applications, microsoft-word

How can I open embedded audio or video files in Word documents? I can play their audio/video files on my computer when I open the document with Microsoft Office, but on my phone, I can just see the text on the files.

Comment: On your computer are these audio and video files opened/played in an another program (such as Windows Media Player/ VLC) or are they played within MS Word?

Comment: @Firelord: They are opened in VLC.

Comment: Embedding video in a HTML document should allow anyone viewing the document to watch/play the video.  @Firelord people should not have to install apps to view videos in his document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm asserting that Microsoft Corporation has not ported this feature to their MS Office and Word apps. Why they have not implemented this feature since so long so is not something I would delve into. My assertion is based on the following arguments I'm providing.

The "technical limitations"  mentioned in a [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-enable-the-audio-file-mpeg4-to-work-on/84d036f7-f443-4630-882c-b608ed86a225) on Microsoft Answers forum has not been explained or discussed. AFAIK, no such limitation exist. Much like how MS Word operates on the Desktop by downloading the embedded media and playing it in an external app/program, MS Word for Android can do the same. In Android, MS Word has to download the media in a location where third-party apps can access it. Download or Document folder under Internal Storage (/sdcard) can be used for this. MS Word can then fire an intent so that relevant apps which can open the downloaded media can play it, or alternatively, show up as options to the user to choose from to play the media with.

If the privacy or confidentiality of embedded media is a concern for not allowing third-party apps to access embedded media, and hence, dropping the feature altogether, than MS Word can create a proprietary or FOSS -- to reduce development costs -- audio and video player and ask the user to install it. This extension app coming from Microsoft can be programmed to have access to private data of MS Word app. This way, privacy and confidentiality concerns would be alleviated since the player would be Microsoft owned and verified.

I'm not an Android developer but I do think that porting this feature is possible. This is a matter of "when this feature would be ported", and not "whether this can be ported or not".

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be possible for Word and PDF files due to imposed limitations of the OS and creators of that software, but however does seem to work for [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374889)

[Audio](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)
[Video](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: What do you mean by "imposed limitations"? What prevents MS Word on Android from saving the embedded audio/video in an accessible location (to other apps) in /sdcard and than broadcasting an intent so that relevant apps can show up in "Open with this app" dialog? Could it not be just that this feature has not been ported to MS Word app for Android so far and that feature can actually work if it is ported?

Comment: You can use links to other programs, but the files themselves do not play in word.  You can create a document in HTML and play the audio/video without the need for 3rd party apps, per say.  I thought that was what the Opening Poster wanted to do.

Comment: @Firelord Adobe doesn't seem to support Android for multimedia - https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/play-embedded-media-in-android-mobile/td-p/11925477

Comment: @Archerbob re: HTML, while it may be valid as an alternative solution, this is assuming that the OP is also the creator of the document, not a recipient.